# ERROR: syntax error at or near "-" - SUBQUERY

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Goal**

I have two tables with values that should be subtracted, but error is returning me to subquery because subtraction should occur as follows (`TABLE1`.`COLUMN1` - `TABLE2`.`COLUMN1`), and so on.

**Query**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) hostname - CAST(tb_getCountSRVS.srvs AS int)
FROM tb_get_gap
LEFT JOIN tb_getCountSRVS
  ON tb_get_gap.customer = tb_getCountSRVS.cust_code
WHERE tb_getCountSRVS.customer in (
  SELECT customer
  FROM tb_getCountSRVS
) AND tb_get_gap.exception = 'NO'
GROUP BY tb_get_gap.customer
ORDER BY tb_get_gap.customer ASC
```

**Output**

```
> [Error] Script lines: 1-5 --------------------------
 ERROR: syntax error at or near "-"
 Line: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is due to the fact that, in your main `SELECT`, you are giving an alias (`hostname`) to `COUNT(*)`, then you're trying to do a subtraction.
You should correct the first row of your query as follows:

```
SELECT (COUNT(*) - CAST(tb_getCountSRVS.srvs AS int)) AS hostname
```